Add $k$ instances of a certain character
I'm trying to write a latex command that will allow me to concatenate k times a certain string. Both k and the string will be provided as input. However, I'm having trouble starting. I want to make the condition if k=0, to return an empty string, or if k=1 to return a single appearance of this string, it doesn't matter.
As the command I want to write is recursive, I'd likely need to use \expandafter. Would appreciate help on how to write such a command.

Does this answer your question? How to make an \egreg command?.

See David Kastrup's \replicate-macro, GUST, Pearls 2005, David Kastrup - Iterating with roman numerals.

The solution using classical TeX can look like this:
\newcount\repnum
\def\rep#1#2{\repnum=#1 \repA{#2}}
\def\repA#1{\ifnum\repnum=0 \expandafter\ignoreit 
            \else #1\advance\repnum by-1 \expandafter\repA
            \fi {#1}%
}
\def\ignoreit#1{}

\rep5{nazdar!}

\bye

This macro calls recursively itself until \repnum=0. It is not expadable because \advance TeX primitive is used. You can precede assignments by \immediateassignment in LuaTeX in order to make this macro expandable. Or you can use more tricky solution outside the LuaTeX (but I recommend to use LuaTeX).

Yes, it was a good test if somebody will try it:).

The tool is already available as \prg_replicate:nn, so you just need a user-level command for it.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\repeatstring}{mm}
 {
  \prg_replicate:nn {#1} {#2}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

A\repeatstring{1}{xyz}B

A\repeatstring{3}{xyz}B

A\repeatstring{0}{xyz}B

A\repeatstring{2*3-1}{xyz}B

\end{document}



The tool is already available as \fornum in OpTeX, so you just need a user level command for it.
\def\rep#1#2{\fornum 1..#1\do{#2}}

\rep5{nazdar!}

\bye


The simple command could be written like this (this is fully expandable, needs exactly two steps of expansion, returns inside of \unexpanded, so doesn't expand further inside \expanded or \edef, and works in all e-TeX supporting engines that have \expanded (pdfTeX, XeTeX, and LuaTeX work)), but apart from that I recommend using \prg_replicate:nn (that command is very smartly written and has logarithmic performance, as opposed to the linear performance of the code here -- parts of this could be written with better performance, this is just to give an idea on how these loops can be created):
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\providecommand\@firstofthree[3]{#1}
% step one: evaluate the number argument to a string of numbers
\newcommand\repeatstring[2]
  {\unexpanded\expanded{{\expandafter\repeatstring@\the\numexpr#1;{#2}}}}
% step two: check that the number is not negative
\long\def\repeatstring@#1;#2%
  {%
    \ifnum#1<\z@
      \@firstofthree
    \fi
    \@firstofone{\repeatstring@loop#1;{#2}}%
  }
% step three: loop, reducing the number by 1 on each step, end at 0
\long\def\repeatstring@loop#1;#2%
  {%
    \ifx0#1% only the case on done
      \repeatstring@end
    \fi
    \unexpanded{#2}%
    \expandafter\repeatstring@loop\the\numexpr#1-1;{#2}%
  }
\long\def\repeatstring@end\fi#1;#2{\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
A\repeatstring{0}{x}B
A\repeatstring{10}{x}B
A\repeatstring{5}{xy}B
A\repeatstring{-5}{xy}B
\end{document}


Because David is mocking me, an (almost \expandafter-less) variant that still works by expansion but doesn't step any counter. Instead it uses \romannumeral to generate a number of m tokens over which we loop:
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
% step one: create m tokens
\newcommand\repeatstring[2]
  {%
    \unexpanded\expanded
      {{\expandafter\repeatstring@\romannumeral\the\numexpr#1\relax000;{#2}}}%
  }
% step two: reorder some arguments
\long\def\repeatstring@#1;#2{\repeatstring@@{#2}#1;\repeatstring@end}
% step three: loop
\newcommand\repeatstring@@[2]
  {%
    \repeatstring@ifsemicolon#2\repeatstring@end;%
    \unexpanded{#1}\repeatstring@@{#1}%
  }
% fast test for a known token: gobble everything up to the known token
\def\repeatstring@ifsemicolon#1;{}
\long\def\repeatstring@end#1\repeatstring@end{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
A\repeatstring{0}{x}B
A\repeatstring{10}{x}B
A\repeatstring{5}{xy}B
A\repeatstring{-5}{xy}B
\end{document}


sad, I expected you to use your roman number skills:)

@DavidCarlisle that's your business :) More seriously: OP explicitly asked about a recursive implementation.

@DavidCarlisle and I added it. My brain just didn't want to see that this is still recursion.

you learned from a great master

An implementation that leverages LaTeX3's syntax would as follows.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% Define an internal auxiliary command for recursive repetition
\cs_new:Npn \__repeatstring_aux:nn #1#2
  {
    % Check if the repetition count is 0
    \int_compare:nTF {#1 = 0}
      { } % If k = 0, return an empty string
      {
        % If k is not 0, check if it's 1
        \int_compare:nTF {#1 = 1}
          {#2} % If k = 1, return the string itself
          {
            % If k > 1, output the string and recursively call the function
            #2 % Output the current string
            % Recursively call the function with decremented count
            \__repeatstring_aux:nn {\int_eval:n {#1 - 1}} {#2}
          }
      }
  }

% Define the user-level command \repeatstring
% #1: The number of times to repeat the string
% #2: The string to be repeated
\NewDocumentCommand \repeatstring {mm}
  {
    % Call the internal auxiliary function with the provided arguments
    \__repeatstring_aux:nn {#1} {#2}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

% Test cases
\repeatstring{0}{abc} % Should produce nothing

\repeatstring{1}{abc} % Should produce abc

\repeatstring{3}{abc} % Should produce abcabcabc

\repeatstring{5}{xyz} % Should produce xyzxyzxyzxyzxyz

\repeatstring{14}{NaN} Batman! % https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat

\end{document}


why not \prg_replicate:nn  ?

I simply didn't know it existed :)

In the meantime I did some practice writing some code in latex3
